# How to have sectionpages continue across multiple sections in word?

Tags: microsoft-word, page-numbers, footers, landscape

The problem:
I have a standard template my company uses that has 2 sections:

- Section 1 pages numbered using roman numerals, footer is page "page"
- Section 2 pages numbered using numeric digits, footer is "page" of "SectionPages"

Example of what the document looks like
page i
page ii
page 1 of 5
page 2 of 5
page 3 of 5
page 4 of 5
page 5 of 5

However, within section 2 I now have some landscape pages, which has caused the following problem:
page i
page ii
page 1 of 2
page 2 of 2
-landscape starts here-
page 1 of 3
page 2 of 3
page 3 of 3

I can use "continue from previous section" to get the following:
page i
page ii
page 1 of 2
page 2 of 2
-landscape starts here-(continue from previous section)
page 3 of 3
page 4 of 3
page 5 of 3

If I change "SectionPages" into "NumPages" I get:
page i
page ii
page 1 of 7
page 2 of 7
-landscape starts here-(continue from previous section)
page 3 of 7
page 4 of 7
page 5 of 7

What can I do to make "SectionPages" count over sections 2 and 3 as if they were a single section?  Continue from previous section has applied to the page number, but not to the section page count :(

Or alternately, how can I switch to landscape but not have that force a new section to begin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can't, exactly, but you can use a calculation field.

When you switch from Portrait to Landscape orientation, you create a new section again. SectionPages reflects the pages in the section.

Taking the simplest example, you will always have two pages in your front matter. You want to subtract 2 from your NumPages to get your number.

`{ = { NumPages } - 2 }` instead of `{ NumPages }`.

For more complex situations, you could make this dynamic with one or more bookmarked hidden Page fields on the last page of your sections and using those numbers to add or subtract and get your body total. This is examined in Greg Maxey's [page on using two page numbering schemes in a document](http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/page_numbering.html).

- Here is my article on the Microsoft site about [Dealing with and Editing Fields](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/dealing-with-fields-in-microsoft-word/e1bdddad-5a51-4327-837c-c3786c16a501).
- Here is my writing on [Pagination Fields](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#Pagination).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer!  This is the approach I have taken and it has allowed the page numbers to be displayed "correctly" i.e. as the company template intends.
A weakness is, as you mention, using hidden information and bookmarks to calculate the value to subtract could easily be broken by a user unintentionally.  Editing these fields I also found to be complex for someone not familiar with them.